# PHP problema em variável com pelicas

Tags: php, mysql, input, text

Estou a trazer esta variável da base de dados mysql para uma input de texto, mas o resultado não estou a conseguir mostrar por causa das pelicas.

```
$cota = '946.9"1968/1975" AMA Ant';

echo '<input type="text"  value="'.$cota.'" />';
```

resultado: 946.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz isso:

```
<?php

$cota = '946.9"1968/1975" AMA Ant';

echo "<input type='text'  value='" . $cota . "'/>";
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Obrigado, funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente utilize [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
<?php

$cota = '946.9"1968/1975" AMA Ant';

echo '<input type="text"  value="'.htmlentities($cota, ENT_QUOTES).'" />';
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)</sub>

Comment: Esta solução tambem funciona, obrigado.